# Applescript Find and Remove in Excel

Tags: excel, search, find, applescript

I have been building a script to help my workflow and have been running into issues with FIND and Excel. The code I put together worked for a short time and I don't see what happened to it or why it will not work any longer.

My issue is this... I have an excel list of image data such as filename and shoot name. I am looking to have the script scan through the shoot name column and search for matching names in the filename column and then remove that row entirely. Repeat that action to continue until all rows were checked.

```
EX. 
Filename   Shoot Name
ABC        DOS
DEF        OXL
GHI        DEF
JKL        ASC
```

SO.. In that case above the entire row of DEF should be removed because it shows up in the shoot name column. Below is the code I am actively using and column D is my shoot name and column B is my filename.

```
    tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    activate
    repeat

        set checkShootName to get value of cell ("D" & RowNo)
        if checkShootName ≠ "" then
            set ShootName to value of cell ("D" & RowNo) as string
            set searchRange to range ("B:B")
            set foundRange to find searchRange what ShootName
            set fRow to first row index of foundRange
            set myData to value of range ("B" & fRow as text)


            delete entire row of cell ("B" & fRow)

            set endCount to 0

        else
            set endCount to endCount + 1
            if endCount > 100 then
                exit repeat
            end if
        end if
        set RowNo to RowNo + 1
    end repeat
end tell
```

Right now when I run it the script keeps getting stuck on "set foundRange to find searchRange what ShootName" with the error "error "Microsoft Excel got an error: Parameter error." number -50".

I am newer to code but if anyone could point me in the right direction or suggest alternatives that would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is when "find" does not find any cells. It generates an error. You can handle it inside a try / end try block as bellow :

```
try
    set foundRange to find searchRange what Shootname
    set fRow to first row index of foundRange
on error -- nothing found       
    set fRow to 0
end try
```

For next steps, if fRow is not 0, row is found and can be deleted, if fRow is 0, then row not found.

Comment: Thank you pbell! That and a little tweaking on my end seems to have been the fix I need!